# Problem with LightDM after selecting gdm as default login manager

Tags: 11.10, gdm, lightdm

I installed GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 11.10 and in the install process I chose gdm as the login screen.
I want to switch back to LightDM. I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and chose LightDM but it gives me a black screen when I restart.

Help please

Comment: seems like no one knows

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Ctrl-Alt-F1

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

select LightDM

```
sudo reboot
```